# constraint drag for senocular transform tool

Tags: actionscript-3

Somebody can help me?, I use a senocular transform tool library, but I need to constraint the move in a container.

For example I have a box1 (300x200), inside this, I have other box2 (20x20)... I only can move (drag) the box2 inside the box1.

Senocular transform tool is a library to powered a object with "rotation", "resize" and "move".
http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/transformtool/

Answer (score 0):

You could enable a listener to track the mouseX and mouseY.

```
someObject.startDrag();
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handleMouseMove, false, 0, true);


private function handleMouseMove(event:MouseEvent = null):void {

//define an area
if (stage.mouseX < 20 || stage.mouseX > stage.stageWidth - 20 || stage.mouseY < 20 || stage.mouseY > stage.stageHeight - 20) {


//call stopDrag on your object or move it back somewhere.
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handleMouseMove);
someObject.stopDrag();

}

}
```

Comment: Hi, I know this, but I using a external library... :(

Comment: It is possible to modify the library if you have access to the .as files.

Comment: Jup I try... but... are various files... I try to looking for another library... I need to add a set of transform tools like scale and drag... the scale are when I drag bound point in each corner